# Sum of even fibonacci numbers below 4 million - Python

Tags: python, math, if-statement, fibonacci

I'm attempting the second Project Euler question in python and want to understand why my code doesn't work.

This code finds the sum of even Fibonacci numbers below 4 million

```
counter = 2
total = 0
while counter <= 4000000:
    if counter % 2 == 0:
        total+= counter    
    counter+= (counter -1)
print total
```

This code will output: 2

If I print the counter it outputs: 4194305

I'm assuming it's an issue with the if statement being executed as the while loop is functioning correctly and the counter is also incrementing correctly.

Comment: The short answer is that your assertion "This code finds the sum of even Fibonacci numbers below 4 million" is false. Your code doesn't even seem to try to do that. Do you know what a Fibonacci number is, and how to calculate the series?

Comment: Print `counter` in the loop and you'll see that you're not getting fibonacci numbers. The series you're getting is 3,5,9,17,33,65,... and they're all odd, which means `2` is the only number added to the total.

Comment: if you use debugging software (try PyCharm for example), you can stop a function like this inside its compilation and check for intermediate values. then you would have easily seen what's wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is in the line `counter+= (counter -1)`. You add it to itself (minus 1) while you should be doing this:

```
a, b = 1, 1
total = 0
while a <= 4000000:
    if a % 2 == 0:
        total += a
    a, b = b, a+b  # the real formula for Fibonacci sequence
print total
```

Comment: As johnrsharpe pointed out in my answer, it is `a` that is the fibonacci number (not `b`).  It doesn't change the `total` though (because of how it is constructed).

Comment: @thebjorn `a` will become `b` in next iteration. Saying that `b` is not a Fibonacci number is somewhat... weird.

Comment: The point was that your fibonacci sequence starts with `1 2 3 5..` instead of `1 1 2 3 5 ..` (but since we're not summing odd numbers, the total will be the same).

Comment: @thebjorn Right, so what you've actually wanted to say is that it doesn't yield entire sequence. A nuance but I've updated the answer.

Comment: yes, something like that ;-)  What is proper etiquette on SO, should I delete these comments (as they're no longer relevant)?

Comment: @thebjorn Nah, you can leave it. It's fine with me. :)

Answer (score 8):

The series your code calculates for `counter` is as follows:

```
2 # solid start
3 # good
5 # this is going great
9 # wait, what?
17 # this is going really badly
```

You can't just add `counter - 1` each time, you need to add *the previous number in the series*.

So why is your `total` so small? Because an odd number minus one is always even, and an odd number plus an even number is always an odd number; `2` is the only even number you ever generate, hence that is your `total`.

Generating the Fibonacci numbers is typically done with two variables `a` and `b`, where we start

```
a = b = 1
```

and each iteration looks like:

```
a, b = b, a + b
```

Answer (score 4):

If you watch closely, you'll see the following sequence:

1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 ...

The formula for mapping the Fibonacci sequence is:

[image]

And you only want the sum of the **even** numbers such as:

1 1 **2** 3 5 **8** 13 21 **34** 55 89 **144** ...

So you can map a new formula such as:

[image]

And you will obtain the following sequence:

2 8 34 144 ...

Code example (Go):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func fibonacci() func() int {
    first, second := 0, 2
    return func() int {
        ret := first
        first, second = second, first+(4*second)
        return ret
    }
}

func main() {
    sum := 0
    f := fibonacci()
    for i := 0; sum < 4000000; i++ {
        sum += f()
    }
    fmt.Println(sum)
}
```

In that case you will not need the if conditionals.

Hope that helped you! Cheers!

Comment: If fib(n) is even, sum of even fibs to that point is (fib(n+2)-1)/2. E.g., fib(9) is 34, so the sum of all even fibs up to 34 (34+8+2) equals (fib(11)-1)/2, which is (89-1)/2 = 88/2 = 44. That's the fastest way of calculating it.

Comment: This doesn't seem quite right. The problem asks you to take all the fibs no greater than 4,000,000 and produce the sum of only the even values. Your code returns the sum of the even fibonacci values, where the sum itself doesn't exceed 4,000,000, which is not the same.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my Python solution using the XOR gate. I have initialized the first two values and then in each iteration, I am storing the state of the previous two numbers. The theory is that sum of two numbers will be even only when both the numbers are either odd or even.

```
a = 1
b = 2

a_state = 1 #odd = 1 
b_state = 0 #even = 0

sum = b
output = []
while (a+b) < 1000:
    c = a+b
    a = b
    b = c
    
    if (a_state ^ b_state) == 0:
        sum += c
        a_state = b_state
        b_state = 0
    else:
        a_state = b_state
        b_state = 1
print(sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are easier ways to do this (e.g. freakish's solution), but this version says what it does and does what it says :-)

```
from itertools import takewhile

def fibonacci():
    a, b = 1, 1
    while 1:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a+b


def even(it):
    for n in it:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            yield n


print sum(takewhile(lambda f: f <= 4000000, even(fibonacci())))
```

Comment: It doesn't matter here, but shouldn't `fibonacci` `yield a`? Otherwise you only get one `1` at the start. Also, `if not n % 2:` is more pythonic.

Comment: You're right (it was a silly copy-paste error from freakish's answer ;-)

Comment: In this case `if not n % 2` is not more Pythonic since we're actually wanting to know if it is equal to numeric zero, not just if the result happens to be coercible/interpretable as a boolean false. I understand where you're coming from though, but `n % 2 == 0` is idiomatic for even-ness testing.

Answer (score 1):

**Well I have tried this way:**

```
fib_num = [0 ,1]
for i in range(2, 4*10**6):
    fib_num.append(fib_num[i-1] + fib_num[i-2])

def even_fib(fib_num):
    result = 0
    result = result + sum([even for even in range(0, fib_num) if even % 2 == 0])
print result
```

Whats wrong with that? It is taking too long to respond for script and giving 'killed' error

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should generate all fibonacci numbers below 4000000 using the recursive formula and for each number, if it is even, you add it to the sum.

The formula: [image]

Comment: You meant that he should use the recursive *formula* and not use a recursive solution/function, correct...?

Comment: Yes I did. Sorry for the confusion. You should only use 3 variables: a1 = 1, a2 = 1, a3; at each step, a3 = a1 + a2, a1 = a2 and a2 = a3. and a3 is the current number you are studying.

Comment: @Scooby you don't need three variables; see my answer for how you can use tuple unpacking to skip the intermediary variable `a3`

Comment: You are right. A third variable is useless, but isn't it easier to understand so?

Answer (score 0):

well algorithms is wrong.
counter is always odd, well it's even only in the begining. this is how it goes
2
3
5
9
17
and so on. `total+= counter` is never executes

Comment: Every single output of total is the number 2.

Comment: @nonsequiter yes, because that's the only even number your sequence generates

Answer (score 0):

Here's my Python code. I make use of 2 things. First, that the nth fibonacci number can be calculated as: 
Fib<sub>n</sub> =     [φ<sup>n</sup>-(1-φ<sup>n</sup>)]/√5, 
and the fact that even numbers occurs at every 3 Fibonacci number. This avoids a lot of unnecessary computation!

```
import numpy as np
import time

start = time.perf_counter()
phi_p = (np.sqrt(5)+1)/2
phi_n = phi_p-1
sqrt5_inv = 1/np.sqrt(5)

def Fib(n):
     return int(sqrt5_inv*((phi_p)**n-(-phi_n)**n))

fib_e_sum = 0
index = 3
max_fib = 4e6
tmp_fib = 0
while (tmp_fib<max_fib):
    fib_e_sum += tmp_fib
    tmp_fib=Fib(index)
    index += 3

end = time.perf_counter()
total_time = end-start
print(fib_e_sum)
print(total_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to this problem:

```
l = []
k = []
(x, y) = (1, 2)
while x < 4000000:
    k.append(x)
    k.append(y)
    x += y
    y += x
for i in k:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        l.append(i)
print(sum(l))
```

Output: 4613732

Answer (score -1):

The algorithm should be fixed.  In your code you are not summing up Fibonacci numbers.

Here is a revised version:

```
total = 0

i, j = 1, 0

while j <= 4000000:
        if j % 2 == 0:
                total += j
        i, j = j, i + j

print total
```

Comment: How should it be fixed?

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int total, a=1,b=2,c;

    while(a+b<4000000)
    {
       if(b%2==0)
       {
          total+=b;
       }
       c=a+b;
       a=b;
       b=c;
    }

    cout<<total;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When python is in context, please explain your point of sharing a C++ code.

Answer (score -1):

My simple solution:

```
x = 1
y = 1
z = 0
if 4000000 > 0:
    while x < 4000000:
        print(x)
        z = x
        x += y
        y = z
else:
    print("Error")
```

Comment: Your solution does not consider even numbers. Your variable shall be better named.